# Почему видно приватное поле в java коде?

Tags: java, доступ

Есть код и он компилируется:

```
public class EqualMeth {
    private String name; //Приватное поле

    public EqualMeth(String name) { //Конструктор
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equals(EqualMeth p) {
        return p.name==this.name; //p.name вроде бы приватно
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EqualMeth EQ = new EqualMeth("B");
        EqualMeth FQ = new EqualMeth("B");
        if(FQ.equals(EQ)){
            System.out.println("FQ == EQ");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("FQ != EQ");
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе: `FQ == EQ`

По моему видению, в методе `equals(EqualMeth p)`, идёт запрос приватного поля `p.name`, которое не должно быть видимо. Однако компилятор его видит. В дополнении, оператор ==, как известно, проверяет равенство ссылок. Но на выходе, он говорит о том, что имя `FQ` и `EQ` равны.

**Вопросы:** Почему видно приватное поле `p.name`? Почему компилятор считает что

```
EQ.name == FQ.name
```

ведь у них разные (на мой взгляд) ссылки?

Comment: Последний вопрос объясняется интернированием строк.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev
`String a = new String("asd");
        String b = new String("asd");

        if(a==b){
            System.out.println("a==b");
        }else {
            System.out.println("a!=b");
        }`
Выведет не равно однако.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin в коде вопроса нет `new String`

Comment: Потому что `new String()` создаст новый объект, а оба строковых литера `"B"` будут указывать на одну область в пуле констант.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`private` означает скрытие не от других экземпляров того же класса, а от кода в других классах. Попробуйте обратиться к `EQ.name`/`FQ.name` в `main`.

---

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6

Какие доки? Я в жизни не написал ни одной строчки на языке Java, кроме как в ответах на ruSO. Однако, это именно то, как работает `private` в тех языках программирования, с которыми я имел дело.

> "И прикажите установить на мессере фотоаппаратуру, если вам моего
>   слова мало!"

*Капитан Титаренко "В бой идут одни старики"*

Comment: Можете подробнее? Из вашего ответа что я понял, так это только то, что вы всё отлично понимаете.

Comment: Куда уж подробнее? Все экземпляры одного класса видят приватные члены друг друга, но не смогут увидеть приватные члены экземпляров другого класса.

Comment: Отличительным свойством моих ответов и комментариев является высокое количество информации на символ ).

Comment: @Igor ну вы хоть ссылочку прикрепите на доки оракла или на соответствующую страницу сайта. А то новые юзеры замучаются гуглить, чтобы подтвердить то, что вы ответили. Пожалуйста.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin [ссылочка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)

Answer (score 1):

При создании любой сроки, сначала проверяется, есть ли такая строка в пуле срок.
Если такой нету она туда добавляется, что и произошло когда ты сделал

```
"EqualMeth EQ = new EqualMeth (" B "),"
```

Но когда ты создал еще одну переменную

```
 "EqualMeth FQ = new EqualMeth (" B "),"
```

ты сначала опять полез в тот же пул строк и нашёл там `"В"` и в этом случае НЕ создал в памяти новую сроку, а использовал уже существующую.

В этом случае при проверке `FQ.equals (EQ) FQ` и `EQ` ссылаются на ту же ячейку памяти.

Comment: "мы сначало опять полезла" - вас крайне интересно читать

Comment: @AndrewKachalin гугл переводчик и не такое может!)