# Не понимаю почему модификатор доступа private не ограничивает доступ к массиву

Tags: java

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Mas myMas = new Mas();
        Mas myMas1 = new Mas();
        int a = myMas1.sum(myMas);
        System.out.println(a);
        
}
}
class Mas{
    private int a[] = {1,2};
    public int sum(Mas obj){
        int sum = obj.a[0]+5;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: А где в вашем коде вы видите нарушение работы `private` модификатора доступа?

Comment: Может тут подразумевалось, что `private` позволяет доступ только через `this`? Ну так это неверное предположение.

Comment: Кажется я понял. Вы имеете в виду что не ожидали, что внутри класса `Mas` у переменной с типом `Mas` будет доступ к приватной переменной `a`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899515/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2-java-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5/899521#899521

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я предполагаю, что private int a[] = {1,2}; должен ограничивать доступ от других объектов, а в данном случае объект myMas1 получает доступ к массиву объекта myMas, но ведь это совершенно разные объекты

Comment: @Денис "я предполагаю" - это неверное предположение

Answer (score 1):

Модфикатор `private` блокирует доступ к методу/полю из других классов. Но внутри самого класса это поле/метод доступны.

У вас массив `int[]a` приватный. А значит, его нельзя вызвать в классе **Test**, потому что это другой класс. Но внутри класса **Mas** этот массив вызывать можно, потому что этот класс владеет этим массивом.

- *Вы вызываете приватный массив в методе `sum()`. Это нормально, ведь и массив, и метод находятся в одном классе.*
- *Вы вызываете метод `sum()` из класса **Test**. Это нормально, потому что метод `sum()` в свою очередь публичный и доступен для вызова из других классов.*

Ошибкой было бы попытаться обратиться к массиву a из класса **Test**. А так всё нормально.